# Filter multiple Datagridview with a Textbox without using SQL

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview, textbox

I'd like to filter a DataGridView using a Textbox to find matches in an existing column defined by a ComboBox that has all column name in a collection.

For instance, if I choose "Name" in the ComboBox and then Enter "The S" in the Textbox, the DataGridView only show rows where the column Name value starts with "The S", so I'll get "The StackOverFlow", "The Steak", and so on.

The thing is, I don't want to launch an SQL request everytime I filter, so I'll save ressources.

Here is my actual code where

- `ListProd` is my DataGridView
- `CBFiltre` is my ComboBox
- `tbRefChantier` is my TextBox
- `ClassTables.Produits` is my DataSet that have EVERY entry from my MariaDB database

  ```
  Private Sub tbRefChantier_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbRefChantier.TextChanged

      Try

          ListeProd.DataSource = ClassTables.Produits.Tables("Produits").Select(CbFiltre.Text & " Like '%" & tbRefChantier.Text & "%'")

      Catch Exc As Exception
          MsgBox("Erreur logiciel :" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Exc.Message)

      End Try
  End Sub
  ```

But when I try to Filter it, my DataGridView only shows

[image: A screenshot of a filtered DataGridView, with no requirement in the filter]

But it seems to actually filter since the number of rows changes when I type something

Comment: Tried with `TheView = New DataView(ClassTables.Produits.Tables("Produits"), CbFiltre.Text & " = '" & tbRefChantier.Text & "' ", CbFiltre.Text, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            ListeProd.DataSource = TheView`But now it shows columns but no rows

Comment: Populate a `DataTable` with your data, bind it to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your grid. Handle the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox`. Set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` to `$"{CbFiltre.Text} LIKE '%{tbRefChantier.Text}%'"`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I get "the object reference was not set to an object instance" when the BindingSource get his DataSource. On the line `BindingName.Datasource = ClassTables.Produits` (Produits is now a DataTable)

Comment: Deal with that the same way you do any `NullReferenceException`: determine which reference is null, determine why and then set it to something in the appropriate place.

Comment: I have to admit : I have no idea how to deal with a `NullReferenceException`. I know that my Table is actually filled cause I can fill the DataGrid with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @jmcilhinney I worked that out.

I ended up creating, in my form

`Dim BindingData As New BindingSource`

Then

`BindingData.DataSource = Class.MyDataSetName.Tables("NameOfTheTable")
 TheDataGridView.DataSource = BindingData`

And on Textbox.TextChange

`Try
    BindingData.Filter = ComboBoxFilter.Text & " Like '%" & TextBoxFilter.Text & "%'"
    TheDataGridView.DataSource = BindingData
Catch Exc As Exception
    MsgBox("Erreur logiciel :" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Exc.Message)
End Try`